# wordpress stylesheet not working in firefox

Tags: css, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress site for my client.
I am using Sahifa theme in wordpress.The problem here is,
 the styles what i have written are loading in chrome and working well.
But those styles are not working with Firefox and IE.

I have stuck with this problem for a week and searched everywhere but couldn't find a solution.

My site link is

http://currentaffairs.allexamsmaterial.com/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: we can't just rewrite your entire site for you.  Pick one issue and let us know what you did to try to fix it.

Comment: Sorry.I don't want you make my complete site.I just need to know what might be the reason for not loading of styles in firefox.

Comment: The styles do load in Firefox; they just don't do what you want them to do, probably due to numerous errors.

Comment: Actually there are number of other styles which we cant see with inspect element in firefox.it is displaying only predefined styles from the theme.

Comment: I've downloaded your stylesheet and i'm sorry to say its a bit of a mess and going to be difficult to debug. Looking in firebug, it loads your stylesheet up to line 1892, so I suggest you rewrite this line to be like: 
.ei-slider-thumbs li:hover img {opacity: 1; bottom: 13px;}

Basically removing the stuff about -ms-filter

Comment: can you clarify which styles and stylesheets you see on Chrome but not on FF?

Comment: i have added some styles in style.css file.Those files are not being accessed.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: `Theme Name: Sahifa (Shared on www.MafiaShare.net)` - lol! Buy the theme, don't steal it. http://themeforest.net/item/sahifa-responsive-wordpress-newsmagazineblog/2819356 you will at least benefit with help from the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested my answer and it seems to fix a lot of your layout problems. Line 1892 is causing the issues:

```
.ei-slider-thumbs li:hover img{opacity: 1;  bottom: 13px;-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha

(Opacity=100)";}
```

Rewrite line 1892 in style.css to read:

```
.ei-slider-thumbs li:hover img{opacity: 1;  bottom: 13px;}
```

The line breaks you had in -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100) was causing firefox to stop reading the stylesheet after that point.

Comment: yep, just saw the same thing after OP's hint about styles not appearing.  I think OP can keep that filter, as long as the line break is removed.

Comment: Thank You very much sir...Thank you so much for your help.It make me now to sleep happily.